# Can't get iRobot Create to respond

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create, serial, roomba, communication

We have an iRobot Create connected to a Win 10 PC with the cable supplied with the unit. 
We have followed the instructions here: 
http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/How-to-Use-a-RealTerm-Terminal/16.html
and were unable to get any response except for an occasional single beep when sending a numeric 7 and very rarely when sending 128 132. The remaining examples (and other codes) get no response. The com port the iRobot is connected to is showing VCP, baud rate 115200. (We modified the serial port driver to use the FTDI driver, no impact to the iRobot responsiveness.) - other than that, the real term port configuration is exactly as the example shows

Can anyone provide any insight

Comment: Do you get no response at all in the terminal when you send the reset command (character code 7)? Something may be wrong with either your cable or your robot. Have you tried contacting iRobot? (Note that I am an iRobot employee, but this post is my own and doesn't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.)

Comment: I get a beep. But no data transmitted back. When I called irobot support, all I got was a referral to post a question using the irobot create tags, no substantive help.
I expected a response to the 7 command based on a blog I read but I've not seen it in actual documentation.. should I be looking for a response to the 7 command that would give some insight into the error?

Two questions.. . 
1) is email support different than phone, should I try that?
2) I suspected the cable as well... If that's what you suspect, i will order a new one and give it a try

Comment: Emailing create@irobot.com will get you direct to educational support, instead of general iRobot support. If you reference this post, I'm sure they will help you.